# How do I get the NAME of a UIColor/SKColor (i.e. [UIColor redColor] --> @"red"

Tags: objective-c, colors, sprite-kit

I kinda asked the question in the title but suppose I have a UIColor (i.e. [UIColor redColor]. How do i get an NSString to equal @"red" OR how can i find out is a color is the same as [UIColor redColor]?

For example I have tried,

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];
[player runAction:[SKAction colorWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] withColorBlendFactor:1 duration:0.01];
[self addChild:player];
```

Then later:

```
if (player.color == [SKColor blueColor]) { //Also I have tried 'isEqual' and that didn't work either!
}
```

PLEASE HELP ME! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no standard way to get a color's name. You could create a dictionary of colors and names. But this only works with a finite list of colors. You must use `isEqual:` to compare two color objects. What is `player.color`? Is it a string or a `SKColor`?

Comment: It is an SKSpriteNode so it is an SKColor. How do I make a dictionary?

Comment: You mean `player` is an `SKSpriteNode`? You make a dictionary with `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not know about userData as rmaddy already suggested so I will give you some sample code. First though, this is what Apple says about the userData:

> You use this property to store your own data in a node. For example, you might store game-specific data about each node to use inside your game logic. This can be a useful alternative to creating your own node subclasses to hold game data.
>   Sprite Kit does not do anything with the data stored in the node. However, the data is archived when the node is archived.

```
@implementation MyScene
{
     SKSpriteNode *frank;
     SKSpriteNode *sally;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
         frank = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
         frank.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
         frank.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         [frank.userData setValue:@"blue" forKey:@"color"];
         [self addChild:frank];

         sally = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
         sally.position = CGPointMake(200, 100);
         sally.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         [sally.userData setValue:@"red" forKey:@"color"];
         [self addChild:sally];
     }
     return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];
     SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

     NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = node.userData;
     NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"color"]];

    if([tempString isEqualToString:@"blue"])
        NSLog(@"My color is blue");

    if([tempString isEqualToString:@"red"])
        NSLog(@"My color is red");
}
```

Comment: That would be good but how would i do this since i have my colors picked randomly from an array and it doesn't let me compare colors. I have it set up like:

Comment: NSArray *colors = @[[SKColor blueColor],[SKColor redColor],[SKColor yellow color];

Comment: player.color = colors[rand%colors.count];

Comment: So how would i find out what it is since it doesn't return true if i ask it:     if player.color == [SKColor blueColor]

Comment: i've also tried isEqual and a number of other ways to do the same thing